# So I am making a button in html and not sure why this does not work

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to create a button where when the button is pressed it creates a new div string as shown in the node.innerHtml part. Yet this code does not seem to work, and I am not sure why.

This is the html side

```
<input type = "button" value = "start"  onclick="changeOne()">
<div id = "Checkifwon"> Answer </div>
```

This is the javascript side

```
function changeOne(){
    var node=document.getElementById('Checkifwon');
    if(value() ){ //calls if true or false given by the other function
        node.innerHTML='<div id =Checkifwon > Sorry you died in one shot</div>';
    }
    else {
        node.innerHTML='<div id =Checkifwon > you lived another day</div>'; 
    }
}

function value(){
    var feww = Math.floor(Math.random() *2);
    if (feww === 0) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: To comment in html use `<!-- this -->` and to comment in javascript use `//this`

Comment: change to node.innerHTML+= in both cases

Comment: I am not sure how random is going to be less than zero

Comment: Also writing in a new `<div>` with the id of `Checkifwon` in the innerHTML will cause duplicate ids. ID's should be unique.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have been using lua the past 4 days, so I tend to get the comment parts mixed.

Comment: There, I fixed the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

haven't run the code myself and this is not the best way, but try:

```
function changeOne() {
    var node=document.getElementById('Checkifwon');

    if(value()){
        //calls if true or false given by the other function
        node.innerHTML = 'Sorry you died in one shot';
    } else {
       node.innerHTML = 'you lived another day'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the error, it was the linking the script to my html file and the errors mentioned in the comments. It took awhile, but eventually i got there. thanks for the help.